# How to replace a loop-for of convolutions with arrayfun?

Tags: matlab, gpgpu

I have a for-loop of convolution of 3d matrices in MATLAB and I would like to replace it with 
`arrayfun` so it would run in parallel on the GPU.

I also feel like there is a way to get rid of the loop here entirely, but not sure how :)

Here is my code, any suggestions? Thanks.

```
for i=1:size(obj.W, 3)
   d(:, :, :, i) = convn(prev_delta(:, :, :, i), ...
       flipped_W(:, :, i), 'full');
end
```

Comment: If the purpose is to use the GPU for this task, maybe you can achieve it more directly with `parfor`: http://www.cac.cornell.edu/matlab/TechDocs/Examples/BestPracticesGPU.aspx

Comment: parfor parallelize a for loop across CPU cores, not GPU... In anycase, I tested it with parfor and I didn't get any performance improvement (I have 4 cores on my CPU).

Comment: `arrayfun` (and `gpuArray/arrayfun`) applies a function to *each element* of an array. You're only iterating over one dimension and applying `convn` to entire arrays. Unless you want to implement `convn` yourself I'm not sure that `arrayfun` is applicable. Also, I don't know, but `gpuArray/convn` may be parallelized itself already.

Comment: @horchler convn might be parallelized but the for-loop isn't, seems like a waste..

Answer (score 0):

Will it help to convert the input arrays to struct array and apply `arrayfun`?

I didn't test the code, you may have a try.

```
c = cell(size(obj.W, 3), 2);
p = prev_delta;
cell_p = squeeze(mat2cell(size(p,1),size(p,2),size(p,3),ones(1,size(p,4))));
w = flipped_W;
cell_w = squeeze(mat2cell(size(w,1), size(w,2),ones(1,size(w,3))));

c(:,1) = cell_p;
c(:,2) = cell_w;

names = {'p','w'};

s = cell2struct(c, names, 2);

d = arrayfun(@(x)(covn(x.p, x.w, 'full'), s);
```

You should take care of the return value of d.

Comment: Your code does work, after a few fixes, but it's about 3 times slower than the for-loop.

Comment: @Ran:... yeah, it's just a way to call `arrayfun`. Sorry,I'm not familiar with GPU. As @horchler said, you have to use `gpuArray` to send data to GPU. But unfortunately, gpuArray support only native arrays and scalars, so you can't send s to GPU. Maybe you have to program CUDA code.